# Executing Go Tests Underscore (_) in place of correct path

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

thanks in advance for the help.

On my Mac, when I execute a `go test ./...` the correct "path" is outputted in the output:

```
ok      github.com/cnuss/server             0.008s
ok      github.com/cnuss/server/database    0.008s
?       github.com/cnuss/server/handlers    [no test files]
ok      github.com/cnuss/server/stats       0.014s
```

However, when I build in an Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty container, the path has been replaced by an "_" (underscore):

```
ok      _/tmp/cnuss/server          0.003s
ok      _/tmp/cnuss/server/database 0.003s
?       _/tmp/cnuss/server/handlers [no test files]
ok      _/tmp/cnuss/server/stats    0.008s
```

The change in the path is also reflected in the `-coverprofile` output file, which in turns affects some of the coverage tools I'm using.

So question is, what affects the path that is resolved while executing `go test`?  The behavior on my Mac Book is the correct behavior.

Comment: What's the version of go on each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't have `GOPATH` set in your Linux environment.

If I create a file `src/foo/foo.go` in the current directory with the contents `package foo`, I can see the difference:

```
$ unset GOPATH
$ go test ./src/foo
?       _/home/james/.../src/foo    [no test files]
$ export GOPATH=`pwd`
$ go test ./src/foo
?       foo [no test files]
```

Without `GOPATH` set (or with a package outside of `GOPATH`), it is acting as if this is a relative import.

Comment: That was it, thanks!  GOPATH was set incorrectly in the Linux environment.